# Role based authentication in GAE web endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I'm looking at migrating a JBOSS 4 application to Google's App Engine.

We have a role based login system at the moment, with administrators, domain admins and users.
Is it possible to migrate out user, password ,roles based system to GAE?

I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Java_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status), handlers can be protected by requiring login or admin user when Google accounts auth is used. Endpoints can be protected with [OAuth](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth).

Taking into account your app is using role based authentication, you should take care of its implementation to protect handlers. You may find [this](http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/) article useful to go ahead with your implementation.